# Java Stream combining sum of two different variables

Tags: java, java-8, sum, java-stream

I have a question.

```
public class TestVO {

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private int weight;
    private int height;

    public TestVO() {}
    
    public TestVO(String name, String id, int weight, int height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    
    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + getName() + " ID: " + getId() + " Height: " + getHeight() + " Weight: " + getWeight();
    }
    
}
```

```
List<TestVO> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        tmpList.add(new TestVO("David", "id1", 10, 10));
        tmpList.add(new TestVO("", "id2", 11, 11));
        tmpList.add(new TestVO("Michael", "id3", 12, 12));
        tmpList.add(new TestVO("Jack", "id4", 13, 13));
        tmpList.add(new TestVO("Subodh", "id5", 14, 14));
        tmpList.add(new TestVO("", "id6", 15, 15));
        tmpList.add(new TestVO("Mrinal", "id7", 16, 16));
        tmpList.add(new TestVO("", "id8", 17, 17));
        tmpList.add(new TestVO("Eddie", "id9", 18, 18));
        tmpList.add(new TestVO("Peter", "id10", 19, 19));
```

What I want to do is that I want to iterate through the tmpList and find the sum of height and weight and add "No-Name" when the name is empty.

```
// below into stream 
int totalWeight = 0;
int totalHeight = 0;
for (TestVO testVO : tmpList) {
    if( !"".equals(testVO.getName())){
        totalWeight += totalWeight;
        totalHeight += totalHeight;
    }else {
        testVO.setName("No-Name");
    }
}
```

```
Map<Boolean, List<TestVO>>tmpMap =  tmpList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(test -> !"".equals(test.getName())));
        
        
        int totalWeigt = tmpMap.get(true).stream()
                                            .mapToInt(test -> test.getWeight())
                                            .sum();
        
        int totalHeight = tmpMap.get(true).stream()
                                            .mapToInt(test -> test.getHeight())
                                            .sum();
            
        tmpMap.get(false).stream()
                            .forEach(test -> {
                                test.setName("No-Name");
                            });
        
        // method 1
        List<TestVO> tmpRet1 = Stream.of(tmpMap.get(true),  tmpMap.get(false)).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        //method 2
        List<TestVO> tmpRet2 = Stream.concat(tmpMap.get(true).stream(), tmpMap.get(false).stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have worked so far and It does not seem to be right. I mean I have to iterate each cases.

Is there any way to combine them all together? or any suggestions to make it better?

Comment: Nobody forces you to use the stream API (to solve this efficient via stream API I think you would need a touple type that can be summed-up in a stream). Some times a good old `for` loop that sums up width and height may be easier and even smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the loop version seems to be more appropriate for this task which aggregates over two fields (sum by `height` and `weight`), **and** modifies the state of empty `name` fields while traversing the input collection because it ensures only one pass over the entire input.

Therefore, "stateful" stream operation as `forEach` should be used for this entire task but this does not make significant difference with usual `for-each` loop.  Generally, use of such side-effect operations is [NOT recommended](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness):

> _Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.
> _

So, if the task is split into two separate subtasks, resolving each task separately using Stream API would be more appropriate.

1. Aggregate the multiple fields using a container for the aggregated fields (the container can be implemented as a separate object/record, or array/collection of the fields).

Example using Java 16+ `record` and [`Stream::reduce(BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

```java
record SumHeightWeight(int weight, int height) {
    SumHeightWeight sum(SumHeightWeight that) {
        return new SumHeightWeight(
            this.weight() + that.weight(),
            this.height() + that.height()
        );
    }
}

Predicate<TestVO> nonEmptyName = t -> !"".equals(t.getName());

SumHeightWeight sum = tmpList.stream()
    .filter(nonEmptyName)
    .map(t -> new SumHeightWeight(t.getWeight(), t.getHeight()))
    .reduce(SumHeightWeight::sum) // Optional<SumHeightWeight>
    .orElseGet(()-> new SumHeightWeight(0, 0));
System.out.println(sum); // -> SumHeightWeight[weight=102, height=102]
```

2. Update empty field when needed

```java
tmpList.stream()
    .filter(Predicate.not(nonEmptyName))
    .forEach(t -> t.setName("No-Name"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to do all of this in a stream instead of a loop:

```java
// sums[0] = total weight, sums[1] = total height
int[] sums = tmpList.stream()
    .reduce(new int[]{0, 0},
            (acc, t) -> {
                if (t.getName().equals("")) {
                    t.setName("No-Name");
                    return acc;
                } else {                    
                    return new int[]{ acc[0] + t.getWeight(), acc[1] + t.getHeight()};
                }
            },
            (a, b) -> new int[]{ a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1] });
```

though side-effects in stream operations are generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in just one run in a stream:

- Replace the empty name
- Remove those that had their name replaced
- Map them to an array of [weight, height]
- Reduce the arrays with addition.

I changed the weight and height of the first two, so it's more obvious that the result is correct.

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Testing {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<TestVO> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
    tmpList.add(new TestVO("David", "id1", 100, 200));
    tmpList.add(new TestVO("", "id2", 2048, 1024));
    tmpList.add(new TestVO("Michael", "id3", 12, 12));
    tmpList.add(new TestVO("Jack", "id4", 13, 13));
    tmpList.add(new TestVO("Subodh", "id5", 14, 14));
    tmpList.add(new TestVO("", "id6", 15, 15));
    tmpList.add(new TestVO("Mrinal", "id7", 16, 16));
    tmpList.add(new TestVO("", "id8", 17, 17));
    tmpList.add(new TestVO("Eddie", "id9", 18, 18));
    tmpList.add(new TestVO("Peter", "id10", 19, 19));

    String NoName = "No-Name";

    int[] weigthHeight =
            tmpList.stream()
                    // modify the testVO
                   .map(testVO -> { if (testVO.getName().isEmpty()) {
                                     testVO.setName(NoName);
                                    }
                                    return testVO;
                    })
                    // it changed them:
                   .peek(testVO-> System.out.println(testVO))
                    // remove the ones we don't want anymore
                   .filter(testVO-> !NoName.equals(testVO.getName()))
                    // make an array of the Weight and Height
                   .map(testVO-> new int[]{testVO.getWeight(), testVO.getHeight()})
                    // reduce to one array with the sum of Weight and Height
                   .reduce(new int[]{0,0}, (a,b) -> add(a,b));

      System.out.println("Weight: " + weigthHeight[0]);
      System.out.println("Height: " + weigthHeight[1]);
  }

  static int[] add(int[] a, int[]b) {
    a[0] = a[0] + b[0];
    a[1] = a[1] + b[1];
    return a;
  }
}
```

It gives me this outout:

```java
Name: David ID: id1 Height: 200 Weight: 100
Name: No-Name ID: id2 Height: 1024 Weight: 2048
Name: Michael ID: id3 Height: 12 Weight: 12
Name: Jack ID: id4 Height: 13 Weight: 13
Name: Subodh ID: id5 Height: 14 Weight: 14
Name: No-Name ID: id6 Height: 15 Weight: 15
Name: Mrinal ID: id7 Height: 16 Weight: 16
Name: No-Name ID: id8 Height: 17 Weight: 17
Name: Eddie ID: id9 Height: 18 Weight: 18
Name: Peter ID: id10 Height: 19 Weight: 19
Weight: 192
Height: 292
```

I'm not sure this is more readable nor transparent, than having one method that gets the weight and height, and another method that replaces the empty names.

This one run in a stream feels sort of "hacky". It relies on changing the objects, which I perceive to be a side-effect. See [JavaDoc on Package java.util.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) about "Side-effects". It starts with:

> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.